# How did Jesus walk on water?

Tags: matthew, jesus

Matthew 14:25
English Standard Version

> And in the fourth watch of the night he came to them, walking **on** the sea.

I'm interested in knowing about the sea conditions when Jesus walked on it. Was the sea turbulent? Did he walk with his feet in the water, along the surface, or above the waters?

That is, precisely how does the Greek preposition function regarding the geometry of the narrated scene?

Comment: As you see I have edited your question. But if this is not helpful please go back to yours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Matthew 9:2**  "on a bed". [*epi*/on]

"On" here involves touching what they are "on".
But the person is separate from the bed.

**Matthew 24:17** "on the housetop". [*epi*]

Supported and involved with with the house, but separate from it.

**Matthew 24:30**   "on the clouds of heaven". [*epi*]

Involved with the clouds of heaven, but separate from them as their cause.

**Matthew 28:18"**  "on the earth". [*epi*]

Authority over it, hence involved. But the Creator separate from creation.

In these we see "involved" but also  clear "separation".

**Matthew 14:25**  "on the sea". [*epi*]

By walking "on" the sea Jesus showed Himself to be in command of the natural elements. Jesus uses the sea in His walking and so is involved with it.
But whether He got His feet wet or not He is separate from the water, and it has no hold on Him.

By being involved with the sea He shows His authority over and separation from it.

Comment: You're seeing some significance in separation here, but I don't get where from. The English word "on" doesn't imply any more separation than any other preposition, it just means that two things are in a particular physical relation.

Comment: @curiousdanni If two things are in a particular physical relationship does that not imply separation? Just  "two things" by itself implies separation ie: object A is different/separate from object B. For A to be "on" B is only possible if there is an A and a B. A one thing B another.

Comment: Yes, but that in no way implies any causality or authority as this answers moves to. And does Jesus show is authority over the water in particular? This story isn't like the one where he calms the storm. Isn't he showing authority over gravity here instead?

Comment: @curiousdannii "authority" comes at different levels in this story. When Jesus says "ego eimi. Do not fear" then Jesus is authorising them  to cease human fear. And authority over gravity is in the story. But the question also mentions "how does the Greek preposition function" and what I put I think tries to address that.

Comment: @curiousdannii By "authority over" water is meant authority over the normal way in which the relative  densities of sea water and human flesh interact.

Answer (score 2):

There are three questions here:

1. **Sea Conditions**

The sea conditions are explicitly stated in Matt 14 -

> V24 - but the boat was already far from land, buffeted by the waves
> because the wind was against it.

This is essentially repeated in 30 when Peter becomes frightened by the strong winds and waves.

2. **How did Jesus walk on water?**

Jesus' walking on water was a divine miracle beyond human understanding.  The same is true of Jesus second miracle when He enabled Peter to also walk on water.

3. **Details about walking**

We know that the there was strong wind and frightening waves.  Now, whether Jesus walked above the water, or, whether His feet became wet, or, whether he "bounced and bobbed" along the surface of the water as the water level did the same, or, whether it was calm immediately around him, we are not told so we do not know.  The important things to note are the following that the narrative makes clear:

- Jesus miraculously walked on water (V25)
- Jesus miraculously enabled Peter to walk on water (V28, 29)
- Jesus miraculously saved Peter from drowning (V30, 31)
- Jesus miraculously calmed the sea (V32)
- the disciples' faith was strengthened by these miracles who declared that Jesus was the Son of God (V33)

Comment: επι την θαλασσαν Matthew 14:25 and επι της θαλασσης  John 6:19.  The two texts cited have the same preposition. The disciples said  “It’s a ghost!” Matthew 14:26.  The prepositions ανα and υτερ were not used. I'm trying to visualize Jesus walking "together; close; very short" to a raging sea and being interpreted as a fastama by the disciples, but it's difficult.

Comment: @Betho's - they presumably believed it to be a ghost because they had never seen and so did not believe it was possible for a physical person, like Jesus, to walk on water.

Answer (score -1):

this is when peter came and was the liquid courage in reference to how even with a mustard seed of faith he the man who saw him and heard the voice in the whispering of the lake that man still believed he heard something so he Jesus walked on water to increase the mans belief like liquid courage some men need it to see to believe or for strength

Comment: @ Jod.e - It is best to provide an answer using several "complete sentences."  Although your imagery about liquid courage is unique, it doesn't answer the posted question.  Keep studying the Bible, it's great for the soul!